# Chain and anti chain problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi Can anyone help on this?

Consider the set which consists of all sets whose elements are natural numbers.

I need to define an infinite chain and anti chain, on this set, where the ordering is by inclusion.

So I did:

Anti chain - the set of prime numbers, since prime numbers are a subset of natural numbers and because they are prime numbers , they cannot be comparable.

Chain- the set of powers of two.

I am not sure if I am thinking in the right way, since I do not understand very well the part that says. the order is by inclusion , that is a set A is less than or equal to B if A is a subset of B.

Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: What is the definition of a chain and an antichain?

Comment: chain , everything is comparable, anti chain nothing is comparable

Comment: Do you mean you have to *find an example* of a chain/antichain, or *give the definition of the terms* chain/antichain? From the wording of your question, it sounded like you want the second one, but from what you're trying to do, it seems like you want the first.

Comment: I need to give and example of a infinite chain and anti chain within the natural numbers set

Comment: From your examples, you seem to order by divisibility and not by inclusoin?

Comment: The prime example is correct, in the sense that $\{2\}, \{3\}, \{5\}, \{7\}, \ldots$ form an anti-chain, but there is no reason to consider the primes for this. The sets $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \ldots$ work just as well.

Comment: Your examples are chains/antichains in $\mathbb{N}$, but the question is looking for chains/antichains in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the set
$$
A = \{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots\}
$$
is an *antichain*, since no two elements of $A$ are comparable.  For example, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are not comparable since $\{1\}\not\subset \{2\}$ and $\{2\} \not \subset \{1\}$.

On the other hand, the set
$$
C = \{\{\},\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\dots\}
$$
is a *chain*, since any elements of $C$ will be comparable.  In particular, we will always have
$$
\{1,\dots,m\} \subset \{1,\dots,n\}
$$
when $m \leq n$.

Comment: Is it chain considered a chain because {1} is included in {1,2}, {1,2} in {1,2,3} and so on? Thanks

Comment: @user290335 that's right! You can think of it this way: if all elements in a set are comparable, then they can be "lined up" in increasing order.